# Any Lib or help to create the crosstab?

Tags: crosstab, xtable

I am trying to develop a simple crosstab application using postgreSQL and .netcore.
I need suggestion to get if any lib exists to provide the basic crosstab functions.
May be a method where I will pass Rows, Columns and it will retun the response like below screenshot.
Frequency, Vert and Index
[image]